# Images side to side on html

Tags: html, image, html-table

I'm editing a table where I use only 760 width images. 
Now I need to put 2x 380 width images side by side, but it ain't working out. Can anyone help? Much appreciated!

I've highlighted the section commenting "I'm having trouble here". Please check.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<title>TITLE</title>
<html style="opacity: 1;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#f4f4f4;" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><!-- Header -->
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="760">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                  <p style="color: #f4f4f4;font-size:1px;">Hello
                  </p>

                  <p align="center" style="color:#777777;font-size:11px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;text-align:center;padding:10px"><a href="http://www*********" style="color:#777777" target="_blank">Online version</a> 
                  </p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>

         <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="760">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td width="760"><a border="0" ><img alt="Banner" border="0" height="224" src="http://www.************" style="display:block;border:0 none" title="Banner" width="760" /> </a></td>
                                 </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- End Header-->

         <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" width="760">
            <tbody><!-- Main -->
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="htt***************" target="_blank"><img alt="Intro" border="0" src="http://www**********.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="Intro" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="http***************" target="_blank"><img alt="******" border="0" src="http://www*********/3.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="*****" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="http************" target="_blank"><img alt="******" border="0" src="http://www************4.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="****************" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>

<!--I'M HAVING TROUBLE HERE-->


                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="*******************" target="_blank"><img alt="LEFT PICTURE" border="0" src="http://www********5.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="LEFT PICTURE" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="right"><a border="0" href="https://www***************" target="_blank"><img alt="RIGHT PICTURE" border="0" src="http://www**********6.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="RIGHT PICTURE" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <!-- End -->
            </tbody>
         </table>


           <!-- Unsubscribe to anti cancer foundation -->

         <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="4" height="70" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;" width="504">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #d1d1d1">
                  <center style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">
                  <p style="margin:0;color:#444">
                <br>
                **************</span><br>
                <br>
                <a href="*******************</a>
                  </p>
                  </center>
                 </td>
</tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- Donations --></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>


<table bgcolor="#f4f4f4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#f4f4f4" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
         <p align="center" style="color:#444444;font-size:11px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;text-align:center;padding:10px"><br>**********</br>
    <br>************</br><br>**************</br><br>***********</br><br>***********</br><br><a href="**************">***************</a></br><br><a href=".***********">***************</a></br>

         </p>
         </td>
      </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if you see something that is totally unnecessary, please remove as well.
I'm pretty sure this whole code could be shortened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use tr, td as below for side by side image

```
<tr>
     <td><img style="float:left;width:380px" ><img style="float:right;width:380px"></td>
</tr>

 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<title>TITLE</title>
<html style="opacity: 1;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#f4f4f4;" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><!-- Header -->
         <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="760">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                  <p style="color: #f4f4f4;font-size:1px;">Hello
                  </p>

                  <p align="center" style="color:#777777;font-size:11px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;text-align:center;padding:10px"><a href="http://www*********" style="color:#777777" target="_blank">Online version</a> 
                  </p>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>

         <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="760">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td width="760"><a border="0" ><img alt="Banner" border="0" height="224" src="http://www.************" style="display:block;border:0 none" title="Banner" width="760" /> </a></td>
                                 </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- End Header-->

         <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;" width="760">
            <tbody><!-- Main -->
               <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="2">
                  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="htt***************" target="_blank"><img alt="Intro" border="0" src="http://www**********.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="Intro" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="http***************" target="_blank"><img alt="******" border="0" src="http://www*********/3.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="*****" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                           <td align="left"><a border="0" href="http************" target="_blank"><img alt="******" border="0" src="http://www************4.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="****************" /> </a></td>
                        </tr>

<!--I'M HAVING TROUBLE HERE-->


                        <tr>
                           <td align="center"><a border="0" href="*******************" target="_blank"><img alt="LEFT PICTURE" style="float:left;width:380px" border="0" src="http://www********5.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="LEFT PICTURE" /> </a><a border="0" href="https://www***************" target="_blank"><img alt="RIGHT PICTURE" style="float:right;width:380px" border="0" src="http://www**********6.jpg?1502297240" style="display:block" title="RIGHT PICTURE" /> </a></td>
                       
                     
                        </tr>
                                             </tbody>
                  </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <!-- End -->
            </tbody>
         </table>


           <!-- Unsubscribe to anti cancer foundation -->

         <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="4" height="70" style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:20px;" width="504">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#FFFFFF;border:1px solid #d1d1d1">
                  <center style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:13px;">
                  <p style="margin:0;color:#444">
                <br>
                **************</span><br>
                <br>
                <a href="*******************</a>
                  </p>
                  </center>
                 </td>
</tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <!-- Donations --></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>


<table bgcolor="#f4f4f4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#f4f4f4" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td align="center">
         <p align="center" style="color:#444444;font-size:11px;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;text-align:center;padding:10px"><br>**********</br>
    <br>************</br><br>**************</br><br>***********</br><br>***********</br><br><a href="**************">***************</a></br><br><a href=".***********">***************</a></br>

         </p>
         </td>
      </tr>
         </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I run this code snippet, it solves the side by side img problem, Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. It'll actually misalign the other tables above them, I don't get it. unlucky...

Comment: clarifying what happens when I did your changes
https://imgur.com/a/B51WU

Comment: @Roberto, I have updated the answer, please try this and let me know

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Still not working, they are over each other now. https://imgur.com/a/B51WU

Comment: try replacing <td align="left"> with <td> only

Comment: don't know whats going on, but the solution to your problem will be
1. use two <td> in a <tr>
2. use both images in single <td> and use float style to float left and right
in your code you are using two <tr> for two images, that's y it's coming in two lines

Comment: Ok, for some reason now it works, the second change helped. Thank you!!!

Comment: the place where there is option to upvote the answer, below that there will be a check mark, click that to mark it as accepted answer, I glad to help u, thanks